# Using http for a different github account

Tags: http, github, ssh, environment-variables, config

I'm trying to connect using http for a second github account I've recently set up. When I pushed to https://github.com/usernameOf2ndGithubAccount/repo.git, I always got the following error:

> remote: Permission to usernameOf2ndGithubAccount/repo.git denied to usernameOf1stGithubAccount

That means I've probably made the username of my 1st github account as the default somewhere. But I've looked through all my environment variables and bashrc but couldn't find it to be set anywhere. Can someone please point out how to fix this issue? Thanks!

P.S. I've tried connecting using ssh for my 2nd github account (by using a new pair of private/public key), and that works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the username to use in the URL, e.g.: 
https://usernameOf2ndGithubAccount@github.com/usernameOf2ndGithubAccount/repo.git

Comment: Good one, unfortunately not the email adres, which is sometimes also used for authentication

Answer (score 0):

When you set-up git, it will ask for a username and email. This will we global for all your repositories.

You could see your name and email with (which could be different for each repository)

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

You could change it as follows (only for the current git repository)

```
git config user.name "myname"
git config user.email "my@email.com"
```

To see your/update global config, pass `--global` (after `config`), e.g.

```
git config --global user.email
```

When using TortioseGit, you could easily view and change with a GUI.

[image]

Comment: My user.name and user.email have already been set to the ones that are associated with my second github account, i.e., when I typed `git config user.name` it outputs usernameOf2ndGithubAccount. I don't think this is the cause. I guess is there is some variable overwrites this.

Answer (score 0):

This is windows credential manager problem. Nothing to do with SSH or HTTPS. You need to add the second account to the manager. It only reads the github site not the direct https path.

Bash terminal git config --global credential.useHttpPath true

this will add the direct path not just the github site.

Comment: Weird to assume windows when most devs are linux or mac!